# How to remove notification in xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I deleted the notification text, but the old text still shows

```
        var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent(); 
        content.Title = "";
        content.Body = "";  ---- I deleted the old text from here but it still shows this notification on my phone
        content.Badge = 1;
        content.CategoryIdentifier = "message";
        content.Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default;
```

using the command ctrl shift + F I checked if the text that was in the body was anywhere in the project but there isn't. What could be the reason?

Comment: is this a push notification received via APNS?  Or a local notification generated on the device?

Comment: yes, received via APNS

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications

Comment: and in the case of a local notification generated on the device?

Comment: do you have any solutions for xamarin ios?

Comment: Xamarin uses the same APIs.  If you can find a solution in Swift/ObjC it should be straightforward to translate it to C#, or you can post a question asking for help with that specific problem

Answer (score 0):

In your iOS project add this line after `LoadApplication(new App());`

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();
```

An create a class named UserNotificationCenterDelegate

Inside that class

```
        public class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        {
             public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
             {
//Will silence all notifications
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.None);
//Will play just the notification sound without showing a notification
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.None | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
//Will show a banner and play notification sound
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.None | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
              }
        }
```

Comment: In the WillPresentNotification method, I had completeHandler (UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert); Will adding your code help me edit these notifications?

Comment: Are your trying to edit the notification?

Comment: yes, I trying to edit the notification

Comment: Ok, i don't know if you need to create a new UNNotification, but you can get the info out of UNNotification. UNNotification contains the "Request"property that contains your notification info, but i don't know if you can edit it or just read it. maybe this doc will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos

Comment: where to create a new UNNotification?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new notification with the desired parameters modified (such as a new trigger time) and add it to the system with the `same Request Identifier` as the Notification that needs to be modified.

```
using UserNotifications;
...

// Rebuild notification
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent ();
content.Title = "Notification Title";
content.Subtitle = "Notification Subtitle";
content.Body = "This is the message body of the notification.";
content.Badge = 1;

// New trigger time
var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger (10, false);

// ID of Notification to be updated
var requestID = "sampleRequest";
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier (requestID, content, trigger);

// Add to system to modify existing Notification
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest (request, (err) => {
    if (err != null) {
        // Do something with error...
    }
});
```

For already delivered Notifications, the existing Notification will get updated and promoted to the top of the list on the Home and Lock screens and in the Notification Center if it has already been read by the user.

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#updating-an-existing-notification.